Prove an equality of derivatives

Suppose $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ is of class $C^1$ and there
exists $n\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t $F(tx,ty,tz)=t^nF(x,y,z)$ for all $t>0$
and for all $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$. Prove that $$x\dfrac{\partial
 F}{\partial x}+y\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}+z\dfrac{\partial
 F}{\partial z}=nF.$$

My attempt:
Let $u=tx, v=ty, w=tz$. Then $F(u,v,w)=t^nF(x,y,z)$.
Using the Chain Rule, I have $$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial w}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial u}.t$$
Similarly, $$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial v}.t,$$
$$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z}=\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial w}.t$$
That means I have to prove $$xt.\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial u}+yt.\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial v}+zt.\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial w}=nF$$
which I'm still stuck.
Could someone help me to continue or have other ways to deal with this problem? Thanks in advance!

see $t \mapsto t\cdot (x,y,z)$ as a function

https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Euler+homogeneous

Suggestion: Differentiate both sides of $F(tx,ty,tz)=t^nF(x,y,z)$ with respect to $t$ and then set $t=1$.

This is certainly a multiduplicate. Better find some link, to vote to close as a duplicate, than edit a duplicate answer.
